# return directory structure out of mysql table with filenames

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with a field named `orig_file` and want to get the directory structure out of this table. The orig_file field contains both the directory and the filename. I now use a quite complicated query (which is working) and I'm wondering if there is a better (or more elegant) solution.

```
SELECT left(orig_file,length(orig_file)+1-instr(reverse(orig_file),"/")) as 'directory' FROM tablename GROUP BY left(orig_file,length(orig_file)+1-instr(reverse(orig_file),"/")) ORDER BY orig_file ASC;
```

Is there a function that can return the index of the last occurence of a string within another string?

```
length(orig_file)+1-instr(reverse(orig_file),"/")
```

gives the result, but is quite complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('this/is/test/directory/path/filename',1,LENGTH("this/is/test/directory/path/filename") - LOCATE('/', REVERSE("this/is/test/directory/path/filename"))+1);
```

Comment: don't know which way is better :) but here I am just giving alternative of your way :P